# How to access by() output?

Tags: list

I have a large data.frame containing different forest sites, tree species and their dimensions. For some trees I have *height* and *dbh* data, for some I only have dbh. I need to calculate missing heights for additional evaluation. Height is site and species specific which is why I used the by() function on a *with_height* subset:

```py
tmp <- with(with_height,
             by(with_height, with_height[,1:2], #with_height[,1:2] are site and species
                function(x) lm(height~log(dbh), data = x)))
```

This works out and creates a large list (1144 unnamed elements, 9.8Mb).

How do I access this list? I need either the lm() or the coefficients for each real combination of site and species (without NULL/ZERO responses if a species did not occur).

I found that

```
tmp[[1]]$coefficients
```

returns

```
 tmp[[1]]$coefficients
(Intercept)  log(dbh) 
  -16.36298    11.18222
```

But how do I know to which site-species combination this is related to? And is there a way to do this for all real site-species combinations simultanously?

I already spent hours on that question and would be very thankfull for any help and advices!

Comment: I'd suggest you edit your question to specify things like, what language you're using, and if you're seeing any errors.